# How to create Flux<DataBuffer> based on GridFSDownloadStream class of MongoDB Reactive Streams Java Driver?

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, reactive-programming, project-reactor

The **GridFSDownloadStream** class of MongoDB Reactive Streams Java Driver allows reading data with the following method:

```
/**
 * Reads a sequence of bytes from this stream into the given buffer.
 *
 * @param dst      the destination buffer
 * @return a publisher with a single element, the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or
 *         {@code -1} if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.
 */

Publisher<Integer> read(ByteBuffer dst);
```

Is there a simple way to create a reactor **Flux< DataBuffer >** based on this API?

I would like to use this to create a reactive REST response.

Comment: I don't understand how this can result in a `Flux<DataBuffer>`. `Flux` implements `Publisher` so it should be a `Flux<Integer>`, which you could achieve using `from` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#from-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-

Comment: Yes, it's true, but then I will end up with Flux containing only numbers of read bytes not these bytes itself (real data). The problem is, how to read GridFS data from MongoDB and then use it with the following Spring API:

`ServerHttpResponse.writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body);`

or

`ServerResponse.body(P publisher, Class<T> elementClass);`

any advice?

Comment: The first step would be to convert whatever you have to a DataBuffer.

Comment: I think in the first step I need to adopt the `read` method to Spring API, so I'm going to create my own `Publisher` to wrap the MongoDB API. Finally, I need to convert the `ByteBuffer` to `DataBuffer`, but it is not a big deal.